# already activated spring 1.4.0, but Gemfile requires spring 1.3.3[error]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile, gemfile.lock

My server is running fine but when I try to enter console by rails c, I got the following error.

```
/home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@jugojuice/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup': You have already activated spring 1.4.0, but your Gemfile requires spring 1.3.3. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@jugojuice/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@jugojuice/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@jugojuice/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@jugojuice/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@jugojuice/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@jugojuice/gems/spring-1.4.0/lib/spring/server.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/munam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
```

My Gemfile.lock is as below

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers.git
  revision: 1f08865a10bb06648efc170768c8c9937d441f45
  specs:
    active_model_serializers (0.10.0.rc3)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      railties (>= 4.0)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator.git
  revision: f00b4688542689fcb99f3792d2e691e9a3c474f1
  specs:
    route_translator (4.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 5.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.6.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    acts_as_list (0.7.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    addressable (2.3.7)
    arel (6.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (5.1.7.1)
      execjs
      json
    awesome_nested_set (3.0.2)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
    aws-sdk (1.6.3)
      httparty (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    blazing (0.4.1)
      activesupport
      grit
      i18n
      logging
      thor
    blazing-foreman (0.1.1)
      activesupport
      blazing (>= 0.2.9)
      foreman
    blazing-rails (0.1.4)
      blazing (>= 0.2.9)
      httparty
    blazing-upstart (0.1.0)
      activesupport
      blazing (>= 0.2.9)
    bootstrap-kaminari-views (0.0.5)
      kaminari (>= 0.13)
      rails (>= 3.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.0.0.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.19)
    bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (4.7.14)
      momentjs-rails (>= 2.8.1)
    bootswatch-rails (3.2.4)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    breakpoint (2.5.0)
      sass (~> 3.3)
      sassy-maps (< 1.0.0)
    buftok (0.2.0)
    builder (3.2.2)
    cancancan (1.10.1)
    capybara (2.4.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    childprocess (0.5.5)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chunky_png (1.3.4)
    ckeditor (4.1.1)
      cocaine
      orm_adapter (~> 0.5.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.7)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1)
    compass (1.0.3)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      compass-core (~> 1.0.2)
      compass-import-once (~> 1.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      sass (>= 3.3.13, < 3.5)
    compass-core (1.0.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
    compass-import-once (1.0.5)
      sass (>= 3.2, < 3.5)
    compass-rails (2.0.4)
      compass (~> 1.0.0)
      sass-rails (<= 5.0.1)
      sprockets (< 2.13)
    crass (1.0.1)
    dalli (2.7.2)
    database_cleaner (1.4.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.4.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.5)
    dotenv (2.0.0)
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    equalizer (0.0.9)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.7)
    execjs (2.4.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.9.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    faraday_middleware (0.9.2)
      faraday (>= 0.7.4, < 0.10)
    ffi (1.9.6)
    font-awesome-rails (4.3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    foreman (0.63.0)
      dotenv (>= 0.7)
      thor (>= 0.13.6)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    friendly_id (5.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    friendly_id-globalize (1.0.0.alpha1)
      friendly_id (>= 5.0.0.beta4, < 6.0)
    geocoder (1.2.8)
    get_process_mem (0.2.0)
    git-deploy (0.5.4)
      net-scp
      net-ssh
      thor
    globalid (0.3.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    globalize (5.0.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0, < 4.3)
      activerecord (>= 4.2.0, < 4.3)
    globalize-accessors (0.2.0)
      globalize (~> 5.0.0)
    globalize-versioning (0.1.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0, < 5)
      activerecord (>= 3.2.0, < 5)
      globalize (>= 3.0.4, < 6)
      paper_trail (~> 3.0.0)
    gmaps4rails (2.1.2)
    grit (2.5.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1)
      mime-types (~> 1.15)
      posix-spawn (~> 0.3.6)
    guard (2.12.4)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (~> 2.7)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-livereload (2.4.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      guard (~> 2.8)
      multi_json (~> 1.8)
    guard-rspec (4.5.0)
      guard (~> 2.1)
      guard-compat (~> 1.1)
      rspec (>= 2.99.0, < 4.0)
    haml (4.0.6)
      tilt
    haml-rails (0.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 5.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.1)
    has_draft (1.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    hashie (3.4.3)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hitimes (1.2.2)
    html2haml (2.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (~> 4.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    http (0.6.3)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    http_signatures (0.2.2)
    httparty (0.13.3)
      json (~> 1.8)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    instagram (1.1.6)
      faraday (>= 0.7, < 0.10)
      faraday_middleware (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      hashie (>= 0.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    jbuilder (2.2.11)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.3)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    jquery-validation-rails (1.13.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.8.2)
    jwt (1.5.2)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.9.3)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    libv8 (3.16.14.7)
    listen (2.9.0)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    little-plugger (1.1.3)
    logging (1.8.2)
      little-plugger (>= 1.1.3)
      multi_json (>= 1.8.4)
    loofah (2.0.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    memoizable (0.4.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.5.1)
    momentjs-rails (2.10.2)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    multi_json (1.11.0)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    naught (1.0.0)
    nenv (0.2.0)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.9.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    nokogumbo (1.2.0)
      nokogiri
    notiffany (0.0.6)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    oauth2 (1.0.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.2.2)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-facebook (3.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paper_trail (3.0.7)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    paperclip (4.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
    pg (0.18.1)
    posix-spawn (0.3.10)
    pr_geohash (1.0.0)
    pry (0.10.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-rails (0.3.4)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.6.0)
    rack-livereload (0.3.15)
      rack
    rack-rewrite (1.5.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activerecord (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.0)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.13.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    responders (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5)
    rsolr (1.0.12)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    rspec (3.2.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-core (3.2.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.2.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.2.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.2.0)
    rspec-support (3.2.2)
    ruby_parser (3.6.5)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.1)
    rubyzip (1.1.7)
    sanitize (3.1.2)
      crass (~> 1.0.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      nokogumbo (= 1.2.0)
    sass (3.4.13)
    sass-rails (5.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sassy-maps (0.4.0)
      sass (~> 3.3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    selenium-webdriver (2.45.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    sexp_processor (4.5.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    shoulda-matchers (2.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    simple_form (3.1.0)
      actionpack (~> 4.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
    simple_oauth (0.3.1)
    simplecov (0.9.2)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.9.0)
    simplecov-html (0.9.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.3.3)
    sprockets (2.12.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    stream-ruby (2.2.3)
      http_signatures (~> 0)
      httparty (~> 0)
    stream_rails (2.3.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
      stream-ruby (~> 2.2.3)
    sunspot (2.2.0)
      pr_geohash (~> 1.0)
      rsolr (~> 1.0.7)
    sunspot_rails (2.2.0)
      nokogiri
      rails (>= 3)
      sunspot (= 2.2.0)
    sunspot_solr (2.2.0)
    susy (2.2.2)
      sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
    therubyracer (0.12.1)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timecop (0.7.3)
    timers (4.0.1)
      hitimes
    truncate_html (0.9.3)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    twitter (5.14.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      buftok (~> 0.2.0)
      equalizer (~> 0.0.9)
      faraday (~> 0.9.0)
      http (~> 0.6.0)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      memoizable (~> 0.4.0)
      naught (~> 1.0)
      simple_oauth (~> 0.3.0)
    twitter-text (1.11.0)
      unf (~> 0.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.6)
    unicorn (4.8.3)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    unicorn-worker-killer (0.4.3)
      get_process_mem (~> 0)
      unicorn (~> 4)
    uuidtools (2.1.5)
    validates_email_format_of (1.6.2)
      i18n
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    websocket (1.2.1)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    xray-rails (0.1.16)
      coffee-rails
      rails (>= 3.1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_model_serializers!
  acts_as_list
  awesome_nested_set
  aws-sdk (= 1.6.3)
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  blazing
  blazing-foreman
  blazing-rails
  blazing-upstart
  bootstrap-kaminari-views
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.4)
  bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (~> 4.7.14)
  bootswatch-rails
  breakpoint
  cancancan
  capybara
  ckeditor
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  compass
  compass-rails
  dalli
  database_cleaner
  devise
  execjs
  factory_girl_rails
  font-awesome-rails
  foreman (~> 0.63.0)
  friendly_id
  friendly_id-globalize
  geocoder
  git-deploy
  globalize (~> 5.0.0)
  globalize-accessors
  globalize-versioning
  gmaps4rails
  guard
  guard-livereload
  guard-rspec
  haml-rails
  has_draft
  instagram
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  jquery-validation-rails
  kaminari
  launchy
  momentjs-rails (>= 2.9.0)
  omniauth-facebook
  paper_trail (~> 3.0.5)
  paperclip
  pg
  pry-rails
  quiet_assets
  rack-livereload
  rack-rewrite
  rails (= 4.2.0)
  rails_12factor
  rails_serve_static_assets
  rails_stdout_logging
  rb-fsevent
  route_translator!
  rspec
  rspec-rails
  sanitize
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  shoulda-matchers
  simple_form
  simplecov
  spring
  stream_rails
  sunspot_rails
  sunspot_solr
  susy
  therubyracer
  timecop
  truncate_html
  turbolinks
  twitter
  twitter-text
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  unicorn
  unicorn-worker-killer
  validates_email_format_of
  xray-rails

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

From the error, it shows spring 1.3.3 only. What do I need to change so that the issue is fixed. I am using ruby 2.2.0 and rails 4.2.0

Please suggest what needs to be done to fix this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I fixed it using this.

```
bundle update spring
```